# unix utilities under Android

Tags: android

I have a smartQ V5 device running Android ( 1.6, I think)
Q: I can not do simple unix things (find, more, ... ) on this device.
they are not there. Do I aomehow downlooad them? apt-get is not there
either; is there an alternative?

Comment: Hi Shapour I need to know how to get adb to recognize SmartQ V5.

Comment: i'm also wondering (platform unspecific) how to install these utils?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I aomehow downlooad them?

Generally, no. There is supposedly an ARM port of busybox around somewhere. An Android device is not a Linux PC.

> apt-get is not there either; is there
>   an alternative?

Not for command-line Linux usage. Again, an Android device is not a Linux PC. You use tools like the Android Market to install Android applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Cyanogenmod's busybox from [here](http://cmw.22aaf3.com/common/busybox.zip). You will need to root your phone to run it.

busybox is a single executable which contains many unix commands, including find and more.

For what you want to do, you may find it easier to simply install [cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) on your phone. Be aware rooting and/or flashing your phone is not a step to take lightly, and may result in an expensive brick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an installer, logically, it requires root.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox